# How do I update my collection from a different class than the ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I'm trying to build a simple 2D Game using WPF, and the idea now is that is when I click the "Connect" button, I want to add the player to a `ObservableCollection<Player>` so that the `ListView` with the `ItemSource` of that collection updates. Essentially making it to where I can see the players name when I click connect in said list.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how I should add the player to the collection.. This is what I have now

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:BaseViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="PlayerArea">
            <Border Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Green"/>
            <Border Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Green"/>
            <Border Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Green">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button Content="Connect" Width="100" Command="{Binding ConnectCommand}"/>
                    <Button Content="Disconnect" Width="100" Command="{Binding DisconnectCommand}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <Border Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Green"/>

            <Canvas Background="Transparent"
                    Width="735" Height="365">

                <Grid Background="Black"
                      Opacity=".5"
                      Width="125"
                      Height="200"
                      Canvas.Left="600" Canvas.Top="10">

                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Client.Players}" DisplayMemberPath="Username">

                    </ListView>

                </Grid>

                <Rectangle Width="50"
                       Height="50"
                       Fill="Red"
                       x:Name="localPlayer"
                       Canvas.Top="{Binding LocalPlayer.Position.Y, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>


            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

You can see the ListView with the ItemSource that's bound, and you can also see that I've set the `ViewModel` for the Window to `BaseViewModel` which in return looks like this

```
        class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
            {
            public static ObservableCollection<Player> Players { get; set; } 
            public RelayCommand ConnectCommand { get; set; }
            
                    public BaseViewModel()
                    {
                        Players = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
                        ConnectCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { Connect(); }, o => true);
                    }

public void Connect()
{
    //Connect to the server
    Client c = new Client();
    c.Connect();
}

    ...
```

And inside Client.cs I have this

```
public ObservableCollection<Player> players = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
public void Connect()
{
    //client.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5555), new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
    players.Add(new Player { Username = "Player" });
}
```

And the `ObservableObject` which looks like this

```
[Serializable]
    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I was thinking of doing it when I click `Connect` but I'm not sure how to access the BaseViewModel from the `Client class`

Comment: Since `Connect()` is a method of BaseViewModel , you could simply pass the Players collection to the Client's Connect method, like `c.Connect(Players)`. The Client class would not have its own Players collection, but simply add a Player to the collection passed to its Connect method: `public void Connect(ICollection<Player> players) { players.Add(...); }`

Comment: It seems very odd that you have a base viewmodel with a command, collection of players etc in it. I would think it's unlikely you'll want to inherit all that stuff very often. I'd have thought a players viewmodel and some dependency injection so a singleton can be injected to multiple viewmodels. Or just make it a singleton of some sort. Maybe as a resource. How many players are there one, two... many?  You could have one or two views and select/currentitem a player and maybe opponent out the one collection.

Comment: @Clemens I decided to do that, but in order to modify the collection I had to use the `App.Dispatcher.Invoke()..` route which I guess is fine